# What would Xt and delta Xt equation look like?

Tags: arima, seasonality

I have this SARIMA model, but I need to make final equations out of it. Can you help me out with this one? I am lost for 4 days.

[image]

This is not DUPLICATE! I know there are a few "explanations" how to make it. I'm stupid sorry. I just need to pass this stupid class and never look at it again

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sarima+equation

Comment: Your need to pass a class is understandable, but it does not mean we owe you another answer to the same question.  There are many duplicates of this question that you can find by linking through the search.  If none of them help you, then please edit your post to include an explanation of where exactly you need help and demonstrating exactly how none of the other threads is satisfactory.

Comment: k, if it can be deleted then please do so.